# How do I get a copy of the extended version of the Dune movie?

Tags: dune, dune-1984

So I have heard that there is a longer version of Dune - specifically, the 1984 David Lynch Dune - included some scenes that were edited out (roughly 2 scenes for each character were cut). How can I get a copy of the unedited version?

I know there was a release to DVD but this seems to only include the 2 hour version. Also, I know that a TV version was greatly edited and while it did include some new material, it was also changed dramatically from the original.

Does anyone know of a place to get an unedited version? Specifically, I would like the scenes with the Harkonnen heart plug and the water of life conversion where they drown the worm, which does not appear to be on the extended DVD.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is the [2006 Extended Edition DVD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0007PAMR4) - which, the linked version here does seem to include the almost 3 hour TV cut.

[image: cover - Extended Edition: Dune. (A Place Beyond Your Dreams. A Movie Beyond Your Imagination.)]

From the description:

> If you are expecting the mythic 4 hour "David Lynch preferred" version
>   that is rumored to be sitting in a vault, don’t get your hopes up.
>   This isn't it. In an attempt to quickly sober spice-fueled giddy fans,
>   producer Raffaella De Laurentiis (daughter of Dino De Laurentiis)
>   immediately reveals in the 'Deleted Scenes' introduction that **the
>   rumored 4-hour version is just that; a rumor**.

What does this version contain?

> The presentation on this edition is a drastic improvement from the
>   original letterboxed release. On the flipside of the DVD is the
>   alternate 2-hour 57-minute version cut for television. As many fans
>   know, this 'extended' version was disowned by Lynch, who insisted his
>   name be replaced by that famous Hollywood pseudonym "Alan Smithee;"
>   the name used by directors whose film was taken away and recut against
>   their wishes. There is some new material in the 14 minutes of deleted
>   scenes offering a bit more background into the Bene Gesserit
>   sisterhood, the Kwisatz Haderach prophecy and the Fremen culture and
>   their struggle.

Comment: I think I accidentally bought this for my father a while back - the re-added scenes are unfinished (Fremen eyes are not coloured blue-on-blue, for a start), and there's more recorded narrative by Irulan (Virginia Madsen), particularly at start and end, but a couple of places in the middle, too, but with only storyboard illustrations instead of filmed footage.

Comment: I have this version.  To be honest, if some enterprising person edited all the scenes available in both versions in a reasonably intelligent format, you'd probably get to 3:15:00. Funny thing is, I've seen a scene that's not on either of these releases - a scene at the end where Hawat steps forward to poison Paul then turns toward the emperor and dies. There's a European version that's a bit racier with scenes not on this disk, too. Who really knows how many scenes are out there that could be assembled into something closer to 4hr?  'course, after all this time. Who knows how many still exist?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am purchasing a 1992 vhs and a 1997 from Amazon and will update if there are any differences than what has been shared. I’m going to accept the answer for the comments even though I mention in the question trying the DVD already.